# Ups and Downs of being a 7ft+ (2.13 m) female

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, combat, daily-life

I’ve read about people of certain heights having health and lifestly issues: I've read some have back problems; one guy died from a foot infection e couldn’t feel; additionally, being taller comes with the disadvantage of a higher center of balance and being an easier target.

I know heterosexual females in particular tend to struggle with partner insecurity, finding men who are attracted to tall women or finding taller men that they’re attracted to.

I am fleshing out a character who is taller than most people and is a member of a more traditional-style militia. E doesn’t really struggle romantically due to different social gender norms and es own personal preferences. I would like to make the character more relatable and realistic instead of just being a glaring statue who beats people up for a living.

**What are other possible effects of being an abnormally tall female?** Try to connect health, lifestyle, social interaction, and fighting style.

Comment: This feels perhaps more like a question for writing SE, perhaps ask it there?

Comment: First, this doesn't seem to be about world building, it's about reactions to one human character who is just a long way to the extreme on the bell curve for height.  Second, if it is considered to be world building then we need more about the world - there is apparently a "traditional-style militia" which could be anything from ancient Roman to modern to futuristic.  We can't comment on "health, lifestyle, social interaction, and fighting style" with no idea of the era or society - "fighting style" could be spear and shield or .45 for close up and .50 BMP for long range.

Comment: Would you be referring to a thyroid condition (acromegaly) or just a tall person? (It can make quite a bit of difference.)

Comment: Are such very tall women common in your world? If not this isn’t really worldbuilding, it’s research, and probably better suited to a couple of targeted questions in different stacks (biology, personal relationships, martial arts?) or a good long bout of googling about tall people.

Comment: I think I saw an article not two days ago about the tallest woman being that height. My guess is that is where the inspiration came from?

Comment: @Demigan Most probably. In anycase, I think the question should be divided and brought on other Stack-exchanges. No parameter makes us think it's not identical to the real world, with the exception of social relations. Perhaps. But to answer about social interactions we need details ^^".

Comment: For multiple instances of amusement: look up stories of Dutch people in Asia LOL

Comment: I think I did misplace this question a bit, although I wasn’t sure where to really put it :V. As for the tallness, The character *is* taller than e was meant to be, and is a product of rouge genetic engineering I will refocus the question though-

Comment: 2 things. 1: Don't edit posts to invalidate existing answers. 2: Given how substantially the edits change the context of the question it'd be better to, ask a new question instead of trying to salvage this post. Keep in mind that we have more requirements for posts than just make sure you're asking a worldbuilding question but I think if you first read through the help center's articles on [what to ask](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what not to ask](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) you won't have any difficulties.

Comment: I was worried about that, but I figured I’d just correct the mistake instead of keeping up an off-topic question. Unfortunately by the time I fixed it the question had been closed, so I’m hoping to have it just taken down.

Answer (score 3):

### Health

From a health stand point there are no health problems due to being tall, so long as it isn't gigantism or another medical disorder. Professional basketball players are often over 7 feet tall and don't have unusual health issues.

### Lifestlye

From a lifestyle stand point Height doesn't stop you from doing most things, but it might make working in cramped spaces harder.

### Socially

Socially, depending on the population density, it is possible this person has never met anyone taller than her in her adult life. There are about [2800 people taller that 7 feet](https://percentagecalculator.mes.fm/interesting-facts/how-many-7-footers-are-in-the-world#:%7E:text=About%202800%20people%20in%20the,of%207%20footers%20is%200.000038%25.) Which means this person has an easy conversation starter.

### Fighting style

The main advantage in fighting would not be height, but arm and leg length. The longer the arm, the further you can strike at your opponent safely. because of this there are a few martial fighting styles that emphasize this.

> [Taekwondo is one of the best martial arts for tall people, but some others like Muay Thai or Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu are great as well. Long limbs are generally an advantage in combat sports, but the mentioned arts are the ones best suited for tall people.](https://wayofmartialarts.com/what-is-the-best-martial-art-for-tall-people/)

However, if people use swords or guns, the best fighting style is the most commonly used sword or gun fighting technique that uses weapons that are easy to produce and maintain locally and easy to learn and improve from others.

Comment: Thank you for starting with how medical conditions like Gigantism is no good comparison for what all tall people have to live through! A medical condition is just that, and healthy growth is different!

Comment: On the fighting style, tall people definitely have a disadvantage against people who practice aikido - more leverage to be used against them and there are a few arm locks that legit involve going under the opponent's arm